# Intersection symbols

Tags: computational-mathematics

I am writing a scientific paper. I need to express the intersection of two space, e.g. A and B where A and B can be a line, plane or a 3-D space. What is the appropriate symbol to state this concept. I used the intersections used in the set theory. Is it correct?
Thank you!
Amir

Comment: It's probably fine, but I suppose you could clarify it in the text (i.e., "…where the $\cap$ symbol means their intersections"), if you think some might find the notation unclear.

Answer (score 3):

A line, plane or 3-D space are a set of points. So you could use the standard intersection symbol $\cap$ to take the intersection between any two sets.